# PHP replace double line breaks with <br>

Tags: php, html, formatting, editor, line-breaks

I have a `textarea` field where I allow users to type in plain text or HTML.

I clean the HTML using HTMLPurify, but I want to add a feature to help users who don't know HTML (and thus use plain-text): convert double line breaks (`\n\n`, `\r\r`, `\n\r`, `\r\n`) into a `<br>`. If there are 2 pairs of double line breaks, turn it into 2 `<br>`s, etc.

Basically:

```
Hi, this is some text with a SINGLE linebreak after it.
Here's some more text.

This is some text following a double line break.
```

Will turn into this:

```
Hi, this is some text with a SINGLE linebreak after it.Here's some more text.
This is some text following a double line break.
```

Using `nl2br()` caused problems in that it made using HTML difficult, for example..

```
<ul>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
<li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Was turned into

```
<ul>

<li>List item</li>

<li>List item</li>

<li>List item</li>

</ul>
```

which caused there to be extra bullet points when there shouldn't be.

Comment: I've updated my question with info on why nl2br wouldn't work for me. I've also tried using preg_replace, it replaced any number of consecutive line breaks with <br> (so 3, 4, 5, 6 line breaks would all be replaced with a single <br>)

Comment: is it possible for you to detect when the user is using HTML vs plain text? Have you thought about using an RTE widget like ckEditor or TinyMce? http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Hmm I suppose I could have a checkbox to enabled "HTML Mode" or something..

Comment: You could check and see if what is submitted has HTML codes, and skip the replace if true. That way the 'pros' could keep doing what they are used to. Also, you might check up on 'Markdown' [http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax] which you can add as a library into your code. Cool stuff.

Comment: Hmmm.. I might have to go with markdown or bbcode or something.

Comment: @DrAgonmoray, markdown would be a much better idea than handling this yourself.

Comment: @Radu Hmm probably, but it lacks things like centering :< And it's in Perl..

Comment: @DrAgonmoray, there are [PHP ports available](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+markdown), and you can always center with [inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) or maybe even add your own extension for centering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution a while ago, and now I am answering my one question. HTMLPurify has an option for 'auto paragraphing'

AutoFormat.AutoParagraph

Answer (score 1):

Does nl2br work for you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

It might be HTMLPurify, instead try strip_tags() and use nl2br(), if this works then it is deffinitely HTMLPurify that is causing the problem.

You can also try nl2br() before using HTMLPurify, in that way you would have converted all the `\n\r` into `<br />` before the HTMLPurify and respect the `<br />` added.

Answer (score 0):

Try [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string
>
> Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).